# Dynamically select cells in a row in Excel for using in a Graphic Chart

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I´m kind of basic Excel user, so perhaps mi question is stupid but I´m really lost. So, I´m looking the way of generate a report in Excel by simply pasting a CSV content in a page inside a SpreadSheet.

The graph uses certain columns to get data and I need a way to select the column, from the first cell after header to last cell with content. I know I can do this manually but the main need here is to automatise the task. Just by pasting the new CSV info, the rest of pages on report (graphs) update automatically.

The real use is for Social Media, Analytics and Email Marketing stats.

Hope somebody can help me.

[image: A visual of what I need to accomplish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered extensively on this stack question: [Dynamic chart range using INDIRECT: That function is not valid (despite range highlighted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272728/dynamic-chart-range-using-indirect-that-function-is-not-valid-despite-range-hi) Hope one of the many approaches shown will fit your needs. Cheers,