# One year chart, including zero values that should be hidden

Tags: excel, charts

I have stumbled upon a trouble when I am trying to make a one-year chart for my business. The problem I have is that I have a table including all months and our sales, and I would like to have a diagram that shows our progress during the year, but without including the months that have `0` values in them.

I have gotten quite far with it, but the diagram still shows the last month as 0 (or at least the line dives to the bottom of the chart). I include a picture of the chart so far:

[Excel chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W892Y.png)

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: I got it as a suggestion when creating the post, so I guessed it would be good to have, I do not really know what a high-chart is. I have deleted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `INDIRECT` function to generate your range of values will help you. I had your exact situation once and I found the solution [here - Dynamic Chart Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272728/dynamic-chart-range-using-indirect-that-function-is-not-valid-despite-range-hi).

Tinker with the `INDIRECT` function to exclude all the months that have '0' sales and you'll get the range as required.